# If I were...., I would be

Tags: verbs, conditional-constructions, tense-agreement

The question is "If you could be any age, what age would you be?"

The answer: ***(assuming I am teen)***

"If I could be any age, I would be 20 because I **can/could** drive a car."

"If I could be any age, I would be 30 because I **want/would want** to see my baby."

Are both answers correct?

Does the conjunction **"because"** change the verb tense (after it) to present or does it remain future tense?

How does this conditional work?

Comment: I found something on internet http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/could-can-and-would

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you can use "could" or "would"

"...I would/could drive a car"

"...I would/could see my baby"

It's just the difference between saying "will" or "can" in the conditional tense, hence "could" makes more sense, because you are talking about something hypothetical. The conjunction "because" isn't affecting anything, it would be the same without it.

The below usages seem most natural to me:

"If I could X, then I could Y"

"If i could X, then I would be able to Y"

Comment: Just adding on to Tom B's correct answer, having only *want* in the second sentence would be incorrect. You must include the *would* before it because it's hypothetical: "I *would want* to see..."

Comment: In other words, ***no present after because***. Perhaps that  should be spelled out to the OP.

Comment: @Lambie: ***no present after because???*** That's one of the most misleading pieces of advice I've seen. Lennon and McCartney's grammar was perfectly fine when he wrote "Because the world is round, it turns me on ... Because the wind is high, it blows my mind ... Because the sky is blue, it makes me cry..." (Although you could argue about his logic :-) )

Comment: @PeterShor You cannot possibly think I mean in all cases? Because when I mean something in all cases, I would probably say it.